# How to install ubuntu on a wiped out computer

Tags: system-installation

How do I install ubuntu on a wiped out computer, when I already have a flash drive loaded with the ubuntu software?

Comment: What do you mean by "a wiped out computer"

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: probably a second hand computer without any OS...  ;-)

Comment: @Fabby - Just making sure "a wiped out computer" does not include hardware problems like a bad hard drive or what not.

Answer (score 0):

Just set in BIOS boot order to your USB flash drive and save&exit. If your flash drive prepared correctly to boot - you'll see a welcome screen of Ubuntu installation